# How contious send data via socket get or sending data in every second

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi

I make some program to send data from raspberry to pc using socket communication. so I want to make raspberry to keep sending data in every second via socket if my pc send command "RUN". and stop if my pc send command "STOP".

client.py

```
.
.
.
def setupSocket():
    try :
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((host, port))
        return s,'CONNECT'
    except socket.error as msg:
        print(msg)


def sendReceive(s, message):
    try:
        s.send(str.encode(message))
        reply = s.recv(1024)
        reply = reply.decode('utf-8')

        print(reply)
        return reply
    except:
        return 'ERR'

if __name__=='__main__':
    s = setupSocket()
    while True:
        data = sendReceive(s,'GET')
        sleep(1)

    s.close()
```

server.py
    import socket
    from random import randint,random

```
host = ''
port = 5560


def setupServer():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print("Socket created.")
    try:
        s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 5560))
##        s.bind((host, port))
    except socket.error as msg:
        print(msg)
    print("Socket bind comlete.")
    return s

def setupConnection():
    s.listen(1) 
    conn, address = s.accept()
    print("Connected to: " + address[0] + ":" + str(address[1]))
    return conn

def getDustData():
    data = 'some data'
    return str(data)

def GET():
    data = getDustData()
    reply = 'MSG'+' '+data
    return reply

def dataTransfer(conn):
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        dataMessage = data.split(' ', 1)
        command = dataMessage[0]
        print(command)

        if command == 'GET':
            reply = GET()
        else:
            reply = 'Unknown Command'
        conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
    conn.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    s = setupServer()
    while True:
        try:
            conn = setupConnection()
            dataTransfer(conn)
        except:
            pass
```

so how to make server keep sending data if command=='RUN' and my client keep listen to server

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make raspberry to keep sending data in every second via socket if my pc send command "RUN". and stop if my pc send command "STOP".

You can set a timeout on the socket.recv() operation and upon the timeout act as if a `GET` command were received. For this purpose change

```
        data = conn.recv(1024)
```

to

```
        try:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
        except socket.timeout:
            data = b'GET'           # simulate GET command on timeout
```

and add the handling of the `RUN` and `STOP` commands:

```
        reply = ''
        if command == 'GET':
            reply = GET()
        elif command == 'RUN':
            conn.settimeout(1)      # activate timeout for recv()
        elif command == 'STOP':
            conn.settimeout(None)   # deactivate timeout for recv()
```